How do I extract a single file from a large (1 TB) afio archive?
I have to restore a single file from a fairly large (~ 1 TB) afio archive I created by using the following script (debug messages omitted):
#!/bin/bash
# 
SRCDIR=/bak
BAKDEV=/dev/disk/by-partlabel/Elements
BAKDIR=/media/Elements
BAKFILE=$BAKDIR/$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M).afio
LOGFILE=/var/log/backup.log
ZIP_UTILITY=/usr/bin/pigz

mount $BAKDEV $BAKDIR
OLDFILE=$(ls -ptr $BAKDIR | grep -v "\/" | head -1)
rm $BAKDIR/$OLDFILE
find -L $SRCDIR -maxdepth 10 | afio -oZP $ZIP_UTILITY $BAKFILE &> $LOGFILE
ls -al $BAKDIR >> $LOGFILE
df -h >> $LOGFILE
umount $BAKDEV

afio version is 2.5.1.
Now it's a waste of time and energy to restore the whole archive because there is only one file (size: ~ 150 MB) to get dug out of the archive, uncompressed and stored on disk. The -p option seems not to be a solution, as it's not available with compressed archives (-Z option). So: What shall I do here?

hi! Never heard of afio, and your question is the literally only one with that tag: could you help me with any direction to documentation or a source for that program?

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/afio.1.html

Any reason why you did not read the man page???? - Extract a single named file from an archive on /dev/tape: afio -i -v -Z -y /home/me/thedir/thefile /dev/tape (If   these   do   not  exist  yet,  afio  will  also  create  the  enclosing  directories /home/me/myfiledir under current working directory.) And just drop -Z since  no compression.

That's the issue: May archive IS compressed! And why does the manpage say that extracting single files cannot be used with the -Z option.

I have no idea what you are talking about. The man page does give explicit details of when it cannot be used, specifically with the -p option and others, but I do not see why you need it. You have also not told us what happens when you try using the example as stated.

Wow, this script is a very bad idea! First you delete the old backup, before making a new backup. What if the new backup fails, because as you copy all these files to backup, you stress your origin storage, and it finally fails! Congratulations, you chose the literally worst possible point in time to delete your backup!

the find | afio is also a very bad idea. I give you one file with a line break in its name, and it might break your whole backup, without you noticing, until you try to use it. Great!

@MarcusMüller I had no alternative than to do it this way as my backup drive is too small (only 3 TB). Nevertheless, this is not my original question.

The cited man page indicates you can actually extract a file from a compressed archive. In fact, that's one of the explicitly stated examples:

Extract a single named file from an archive on /dev/tape:
afio -i -v -Z -y /home/me/thedir/thefile /dev/tape


Here, the -Z is necessary to make sure the uncompression of the compressed file is done. (however, your large file will not even be compressed – by default, the man page says, files larger than 200 MB aren't compressed; whoever thought that was a good idea… the whole "we can't use compression because it will make it more likely that a large file gets broken in the case of storage errors" is a bit of a bad argument, because it's not hard to see that a compressed file will then have a) less probability of error, since its got less bytes that can be wrong and b) if that is a realistic concern, your storage format needs forward error correction in addition to compression, and not no compression.)
So, this should "just" work. You can also try uncompressing with cpio – the format seems to be kept compatible.
You asking here is a backup failure; no excuses.
This really should be a wakeup call. If this is a backup you rely on, check your tooling. There's all: better archivers, better compressors, and better file formats for these out there, who will on top of being faster would also be easier to use and actively maintained:
The website listed in the man page seems to have been dead for a rather long time now, the author thankfully moved the source code to github, where he says he's not fixing new bugs anymore, and you should move to different tools.
The thing here is: these are clearly backups. If you need the software to restore these, you need to make sure the software still works. If, in the year 2025, for any reasons, afio can't be compiled with contemporary compilers anymore, you will be responsible for making it work again, in addition to the stressful situation you're in when you need to actually use a backup.
So, this is an excellent point in time to think about switching archivers. In your use case, you could think about a simple script that is only
#!/bin/bash
# fail on an error. Don't make the user think everything worked when it didn't.
# THIS IS A BACKUP SCRIPT: WE DON'T PLAY AROUND.
set -e
 
SRCDIR=/bak
BAKDEV=/dev/disk/by-partlabel/Elements
BAKDIR=/media/Elements
BAKFILE=$BAKDIR/$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M).squash
mount $BAKDEV $BAKDIR

# create a compressed archive. Compressor set to higher compression than gzip/pigz will
# achieve, but typically at much higher speed. 
# I've disabled duplicate checking. It makes a lot of sense if the data you're backing
# up is having repetitive files or sectors, but in your case, it might not be relevant.
mksquashfs "${SRCDIR}" "${BAKFILE}" -no-duplicates -comp zstd -Xcompression-level 6
umount $BAKDEV

I removed all your logging; it's not useful: you can see the free space of your file system as soon as you ask your file system, and you can see the file name of your latest backup from, well, the file name of the latest backup. If you can't trust your file system to keep that file metadata, you can't trust it to keep the actual backup data. You can trust it, so this log makes no sense. Also, if you need to log that you did a backup on a given date, then clearly that log being on the backup medium is useless; it would make sense to email a success message to an external email address, so the admin can check from outside the burning building when the last backup was made, or whether they need to inform a bankrupcy manager.
I also removed the "deleting" part. I'd strongly recommend that if (and only if) you do decide it's a good idea to actually delete your backups automatically, then you do it  after you successfully made a new backup, not before. I promise, deleting old backups when you make a new one is very rarely the right approach. On the contrary, it indicates that what you wanted was an incremental backup, but what you did instead was an unnecessarily complicated, and destructive complete backup each time.
Deleting before making a new one would be, excuse my frank wording, dangerously stupid: making a backup is exactly the moment you exercise your origin medium's full data, i.e., it's the point where the origin medium is most likely to show errors. And just before you do that, you deleted your backup! Before the moment you will most like figure out that you need that backup. That can't be your backup strategy.
Generally, this all reeks of "was set up in the early 1990s, and not touched since, because backups are no fun and you rarely need them", and here we are, now you are stuck with a program that's no longer reliably available, which you don't know how to use, and to which little documentation is available online. You needed to ask other people to extract a file from a backup! That is actually a no-go. A backup must be restorable when you need it, without external factors beyond your control.
So, take your file out of the archive and continue to work, but at the same time, put the topic of modernizing the backup strategy on the agenda of whoever is responsible for that (or their boss, I don't know your hierarchies; be kind to each other). 1989, when afio was written, not as a professional tool, but because diskettes and tapes of the time were unreliable and they needed something to deal with that a bit, the situation was fundamentally different than it is today: storage errors aren't as important, and if they are, this is definitely not the solution to them. And, 1989, ready-to-use solutions that are less work than the script you show simply didn't exist. If you're a command line purist, I'd say you look into restic.

Poooohhhh, that was an unexpectedly long answer! But let me explain why I am still sticking to afio: In my early years (starting in 2001), I used to use a Travan drive and tar for backing up data until two things happened: (1) I had to restore a tape backup to find out that the process stopped after some time due to corrupt data (and with tar, all data after a write failure are useless!), and (2) Travan media proved too small, so that I had to switch to USB hard drives.

so, neither is an argument for afio. Just an argument against tar, which I didn't even mention. Really, you probably should look into tools like restic. It's honestly less hassle than what you're doing now, and it addresses the problems you're describing with dealing with running out of space. And, already in 2001, afio was obsolete in its approach to data robustness. It is less of a bad idea than gzipped tar, OK, but that's not the benchmark. This isn't 1988!

Really, your space problems are increased by your usage of afio instead of something that knows how to do incremental backups, and can manage the space for you. Your de-archiving problems would cease to exist with a plain repo as restic produces, and it would be less prone to failure than an afio archive

but as you noticed, this is really your business – that's why I posted the short answer at the beginning, and then added a heading signifying "OK, here's what I think what this problem tells us"

@Neppomuk just to motivate my perspective on that: When I looked up afio, I read the maintainer's message that it's no longer being actively developed. Then while I was writing the first part of my answer, I read further through his readme, and here's the "money quote":

@Neppomuk My interest has declined because since about
2005, hard drives have become so cheap that making fault tolerant
compressed archive files for writing to tapes of floppy disks, as afio
can do, has become less and less relevant to the needs of average
Linux user.  I make my personal system backups using rsync on a
detachable hard drive. In other words, for the detachable hard drive scenario, the author of afio himself considers afio the wrong choice.

I will definitely change to a better backup solution (maybe even a tape-based one like a 2nd-hand LTO drive?) once I've migrated to my new edge system, but my previous server has simply become too old to change anything on it. And: The afio manpage is way too chaotic.
